# Extract all links from drop down list combination

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a sample website and I want to extract all the "href links" from the website. It has two drop downs and once drop down is selected it displays results with link to manual to download.
It does not navigate to different page instead shows result on the same page. I have extracted the combination of drop down lists, I am trying to extract the manual links and I am unable to find the link.

code is as follows

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url = "https://www.cars.com/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(4)

selectYear = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("odl-selected-year"))

data = []
for yearOption in selectYear.options:
    yearText = yearOption.text
    selectYear.select_by_visible_text(yearText)
    time.sleep(1)

    selectModel = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("odl-selected-model"))
    for modelOption in selectModel.options:
        modelText = modelOption.text
        selectModel.select_by_visible_text(modelText)
        data.append([yearText,modelText])

page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

content = soup.findAll('div',attrs={"class":"odl-results-container"})

for i in content:
    x = i.findAll(['h3','span'])
    for y in x:
        print(y.get_text())
```

print does not show any data. How can I get the links for manuals? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to **click the button for each car model and year** and **then** retrieve the rendered HTML page source **from your Selenium webdriver** rather than with requests.

Add this in your inner loop:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Select this vehicle")
button.click()

page = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
content = soup.findAll('a',attrs={"class":"odl-download-link"})
for i in content:
    print(i["href"])
```

This prints out:

```
http://www.fordservicecontent.com/Ford_Content/vdirsnet/OwnerManual/Home/Index?Variantid=6875&languageCode=EN&countryCode=USA&marketCode=US&bookcode=O91668&VIN=&userMarket=GBR
http://www.fordservicecontent.com/Ford_Content/vdirsnet/OwnerManual/Home/Index?Variantid=7126&languageCode=EN&countryCode=USA&marketCode=US&bookcode=O134871&VIN=&userMarket=GBR
http://www.fordservicecontent.com/Ford_Content/vdirsnet/OwnerManual/Home/Index?Variantid=7708&languageCode=EN&countryCode=USA&marketCode=US&bookcode=O177941&VIN=&userMarket=GBR
...
```

Comment: I can't confirm this. Your code runs fine with my addition. Where have you added the code? Do you recognize in your Selenium browser window that the right button is being clicked? And have you checked the `soup` and `content` that you get from `driver.page_source`?

Comment: I am writing outside the select option loop. Writing inside the loop is throwing me an error.